# Nested C:OUT tag in HTML:OPTION value attribute

Tags: html, jsp, el

```
<html:select property = "abc">
             <c:forEach var="abcSearch" items="${requestScope.abcSet}">
              <html:option value="<c:out value='${abcSearch}'/>"><c:out value='${abcSearch}' /></html:option>
            </c:forEach>
            </html:select>
```

In the code above `<html:option value="<c:out value='${abcSearch}'/>">` line is not working.

I have tried using `<html:option value="${abcSearch}"/>`.

**But it is not working as well. Please suggest me how can I evaluate this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<html:option value="<c:out value='${pcVersionSearch}'/>">` doesn't work as the syntax is wrong.

But `<html:option value="${pcVersionSearch}"/>` should work if tld for `<html:option>` has configured `rtexprvalue` as true. Please check your tld and change it to true.